# kendo calendar disabling dates / problems understanding documentation

Tags: c#, asp.net, kendo-ui

I did not find much documentation about the server side version of `Kendo Calendar`
I want to disable dates without using any client javascript because of timezone issues.

What i tried so far is binding the disabled dates to a `List<DateTime> DisabledDates`:

```
 @( Html.Kendo().Calendar()
                       .Name(calendarName)
                       .Min(calendar.MinDate.Date)
                       .Max(calendar.MaxDate.Date)
                       .Culture(new CultureInfo('de-De'))                     
                       .Footer(false)
                       .DisableDates(Model.DisabledDates.Select(x => x.Date.ToString("d", new CultureInfo('de-De')))                          

           )
    }
```

The `DisableDates` option does not work, though. I also tried the `.asEnumerable()` extension.

Thats the calendar builder docu:

```
 public CalendarBuilder DisableDates(IEnumerable<string> disableDates);
    /// <summary>
    /// Specifies the disabled dates in the Calendar widget using a function.
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>
    /// <code lang="CS">
    ///  &lt;%= Html.Kendo().Calendar()
    ///             .Name("calendar")
    ///             .DisableDates(DayofWeek.Saturday, DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    /// %&gt;
    /// </code>
    /// </example>
    public CalendarBuilder DisableDates(params DayOfWeek[] days);
    /// <summary>
    /// Specifies the disabled dates in the Calendar widget using a function.
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>
    /// <code lang="CS">
    ///  &lt;%= Html.Kendo().Calendar()
    ///             .Name("calendar")
    ///             .DisableDates("disableDates")
    /// %&gt;
    /// </code>
    /// </example>
    public CalendarBuilder DisableDates(string handler);
```

Unfortunately there is no explantion how `IEnumerable<string>` should look like.
In my case the values would be like `25.02.2017`

Can anybode help me here?

Comment: Is there documentation for first method in builder docu you pasted? 2nd disabled provided days of the week and 3rd binds it to javascript function. Btw. on client side your .ASP code is't javascript anyway. Just check rendered page source.

Comment: I did not find any documentation for this overload

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [this demo](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/calendar/disable-dates) on Telerik's site.

You should do something like this:

```
.DisableDates("disabledDates")

<script>
    function disabledDates(date) {
        return Model.DisabledDates.Any(x => x.Date == date);
    }
</script>
```

DisabledDates can accept a boolean function's name as a string. I'm not sure about the syntax but it should be pretty close.

Comment: I dont see .DisableDates accepting any bool functions. It accepts IEnumerable<string>, DayOfWeek[] or strings. The strings represent the client side (!) function wich will be called after rendering.

Comment: You're right, it can accept a name of a boolean function. I've revised my answer. The one thing I'm not sure about is the `Model` and whether it will be available to the function. Where do you store it?

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted to avoid: using a client side function in order to disable dates as I am facing DateTime vs Date issues than. That's why I wanted to specify disabled dates server side.

Comment: I'm sorry to say but this is the only way to disable dates. It's a method of the calendar itself and you cannot do it on the server. You can tell the calendar what dates to disable only using the .DisabledDates method. The only involvement of the server in this configuration is providing the list of dates. You use this data either with a function like I suggested or by stating the weekdays you want disabled. It has to be client-side...

Comment: okay and what about overload (IEnumerable<string> disableDates) then?

Comment: I don't think you can overload it. You need to know what these methods do when they are called and for that you need their source code.

Comment: Can you paste the description comment that appears above `public CalendarBuilder DisableDates(IEnumerable<string> disableDates);`?

Comment: I would if there was anything. That's the reason I started this topic

Comment: OK try this: leave the `DisableDates` method like you used it in your question above and add `.Format("dd.MM.yyyy")`